# Reshaping issues in R: my reshaped dataframe changes 3 variables into 1

Tags: r, reshape

I'm a relative newbie to R and trying to reshape my data into long format from wide format and having problems. I'm thinking that my problem may be due to having made the data.frame from a data.frame that I have created in R, getting mean values of the large data.frame into another data.frame.

What I have done is this created an empty data.frame (ndf):

```
ndf <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 3))
```

Then used lapply to get the means from the large data.frame (ldf) into separate columns in the new data.frame, with the year being used from the large data.frame:

```
ndf$Year <- names(ldf)
ndf$col1 <- lapply(ldf, function(i) {mean(i$col1)})
ndf$col2 <- lapply(ldf, function(i) {mean(i$col2)})
etc.
```

The melted function in reshape2 does not work apparently because there are non-atomic 'measure' columns.

For using the reshape base function I have used the code:

```
reshape.ndf <- reshape(ndf, 
                    varying = list(names(ndf)[2:7]), 
                    v.names = "cover",
                    timevar = "species",
                    times = names(ndf[2:7]),
                    new.row.names = 1:1000,
                    direction = "long")
```

My output is then essentially just using the first row for the variables. So my wide data.frame looks like this (sorry for the strange names):

```
Year Cladonia.portentosa Erica.tetralix Eriophorum.vaginatum  
1 2014               11.75             35                   55     
2 2015               15.75          25.75                   70      
3 2016               22.75              5                 37.5
```

And the long data.frame looks like this:

```
Year             species cover id
1 2014 Cladonia.portentosa 11.75  1
2 2015 Cladonia.portentosa 11.75  2
3 2016 Cladonia.portentosa 11.75  3
4 2014      Erica.tetralix 35.00  1
5 2015      Erica.tetralix 35.00  2
6 2016      Erica.tetralix 35.00  3
```

Where the "cover" column should have the value from each year put into the cell with the corresponding year.

Please could someone tell me where I've gone wrong!?

Comment: How can this be used `names(ndf[2:7])` when there are only 4 columns in your wide data?

Comment: have you tried `tidyr::gather()`? if not, check it out. it is basically the successor to reshape2.

Comment: 42 - I have only shown a portion of the data set, I was trying to reduce confusion but forgot to change the code to represent what I have shown.

Comment: @roman - I looked into 'gather()_' but maybe not thoroughly enough. I will try again and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of 'melting' in `tidyr`.

You'll need `tidyr` but I also like `dplyr` and am including it here to encourage its use along with the rest of the tidyverse. You'll find endless great tutorials on the web...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Let's use iris as an example, I want a long form where species, variable and value are the columns.

```
data(iris)
```

Here it is with `gather()`. we specify that variable and value are the column names for the new 'melted' columns. we also specify that we do not want to melt the column Species which we want to remain its own column.

```
iris_long <- iris %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Species)
```

inspect the `iris_long` object to make sure it worked.

Comment: Thanks @roman - I actually just tried gather() on my dataset after your comment and it worked perfectly! I'm not sure what I did wrong when I tried it before, I might have been rushing at the end of the day.

Comment: awesome! glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to roman's answer, I thought I would share exactly what I did with my data set.

My initial "wide" data.frame `ndf` looked like this:

```
Year Cladonia.portentosa Erica.tetralix Eriophorum.vaginatum  
1 2014               11.75             35                   55     
2 2015               15.75          25.75                   70      
3 2016               22.75              5                 37.5
```

I used downloaded `tidyr`

```
install.packages("tidyr")
```

Then selected the package

```
library(tidyr)
```

I then used the `gather()` function in the `tidyr` package to gather the `species` columns `Cladonia.portentosa` `Erica.tetralix` and `Eriophorum.vaginatum` together into one column, with a `cover` column in the new "long" data.frame.

```
long.ndf <- ndf %>% gather(species, cover, Cladonia.portentosa:Eriophorum.vaginatum)
```

Easy peasy!
Thanks again to roman for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering your question in case it may help someone using `reshape` function.

> Please could someone tell me where I've gone wrong!?

You have not specified parameter `idvar` and `reshape` has created one for you named `id`. In order to avoid it, just add to your code the line `idvar = "Year"` :

```
ndf <- read.table(text = 
  "Year Cladonia.portentosa Erica.tetralix Eriophorum.vaginatum
    1 2014               11.75             35                   55     
    2 2015               15.75          25.75                   70      
    3 2016               22.75              5                 37.5", 
  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)

reshape.ndf <- reshape(ndf, 
  varying = list(names(ndf)[2:4]), 
  v.names = "cover",
  idvar = "Year",
  timevar = "species",
  times = names(ndf[2:4]),
  new.row.names = 1:9,
  direction = "long")
```

The result looks as you were expecting

```
reshape.ndf
  Year              species cover
1 2014  Cladonia.portentosa 11.75
2 2015  Cladonia.portentosa 15.75
3 2016  Cladonia.portentosa 22.75
4 2014       Erica.tetralix 35.00
5 2015       Erica.tetralix 25.75
6 2016       Erica.tetralix  5.00
7 2014 Eriophorum.vaginatum 55.00
8 2015 Eriophorum.vaginatum 70.00
9 2016 Eriophorum.vaginatum 37.50
```